# EDataBase error with ClientDataset parameter not found

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I have added new `TClientDataset` in my project, to client. Also I have an Oracle stored procedure that takes `clientid` as input & returns cursor.

The code below executes on button click

```
with dmMain.cdsGetV do //cdsGetV is name of Clientdataset
begin 
  if Active then Close;
  Params.Clear; 
  FetchParams;
  Params.ParamByName('PCLIENTID').AsString := '0022995544';
  Open;
end;
```

On click I have error: `

> cdsGetV: parameter 'pclientid' not found.

There are many other clientdatasets like this and they work good. I copied exactly the same code of those cds', but it's still not working. Any idea what's problem?

Comment: Either your fetchparams doesn't return params or your stored proc does not return one called pclientid. Compare a combination that works with one that does not. You're probably overlooking some difference.

Comment: i have tried to execute procedure in sql block. it works fine. How to check FetchParams?

Comment: Check params.count, params[0].... etc in the IDE after the fetchparams

Comment: To stay independed from the provider you might try `Params.ParseSQL(Commandtext,true);
Params.ParamByName('PCLIENTID').DataType := ftString;
` instead of `FetchParams;`

Comment: param count=1,that is it's returning only cursor, there also must be another input parameter pclientid.Why it may be so?

Comment: I may be just pointing out the obvious here, but in your question you state your parameter is 'clientid' and the parameter you're trying to set in your code in is called 'pclientid'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the clientdataset and datasetprovider on server ,and now it works.